# CSS only works for table and not working for table header (th)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am appending html dynamically using Javascript and want to append some css along with the html. In my code, only the css for **table** is being picked up by the browser, the css for **th** is not showing up.

Javascript

```
var html = "<table class = 'table'>";
    html += "<thead>";
        html += "<tr><th>";
        html += "Name: " + data.name;
        html += "</th></tr>";
    html += "</thead>";

    html += "<tbody>";
        html += "<tr><td>";
        html += "Address: " + data.address;
        html += "</td></tr>";
        html += "<tr><td>";
        html += "Phone: " + data.phone;
        html += "</td></tr>";
    html += "</tbody>";
html += "</table>";

$(".info").html(html);
```

CSS

```
.table {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.th {
    /* not applied successfully */
    color: red; 
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the class `th`. You must do `<th class='th'>` according to your CSS.

Or you can change your stylesheet: Just remove the dot in front of *th*.

Comment: No problem! Please think about accepting an answer when your issue is solved.

Comment: Accepted because this was the first answer

Answer (score 0):

You have the `.table` class but there isn't a class for `.th`

```
    html += "<tr><th class='th'>";
    html += "Name: " + data.name;
    html += "</th></tr>";
```

Maybe try and change the CSS to

```
.table {
border: 1px solid red;
```

}

```
th {
/* not applied successfully */
color: red; 
}
```

getting rid of the class identifier

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is you don't have a matching CSS selector for the `<th` element. The selectory you expect to work is looking for elements that have a class of `.th`, yet, there isn't any.

One solution would be to remove the class selector in your CSS and just use the element itself:

```
th {
  color: red
}
```

(Notice there is not dot)

Comment: Thanks! i made a careless mistake